Difference betwen <input> and {{ form.submit }} in Flask
I started to use Flask a week ago and I'm using WTForms for creating forms, but I don't understand which is the difference between to use <input type="submit" value="Go"> and {{ form.submit }}
This is the form HTML with Jinja
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('home') }}">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}

        <p>
            {{ form.name.label }}
            <br>
            {{ form.name }}
        </p>



        <p>
            {{ form.email.label }}
            <br>
            {{ form.email(size=30) }}
        </p>



        <p>
            {{ form.message.label }}
            <br>
            {{ form.message }}
        </p>

        <input type="submit" value="Go">
        {{ form.submit }}
    </form>

This is the class for create the WTForm
class contactForm(FlaskForm): 
    name = StringField(label='Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField(label='Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(granular_message=True)])
    message= StringField(label='Message')
    submit = SubmitField(label="Log In")

The {{ form.submit }} is from the WTForms module, but when to use one or the other?

There is no difference between {{ form.submit }}, <input type="submit" /> and <button type="submit">Submit</button>. The latter, however, allows the use of icons within the button.
